# Remove redundant vertices in graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

My group is currently working on a project concerning Combinatorics: Graph-theory and optimization.
In the project we need to find the optimal sales strategy to the following problem.

### Background

Defining notation in the problem

- $s(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ Price on electricity at time $t \in \{0,1,2,\dots,24\}$. $[EUR/MW]$
- $K \in \mathbb{R}$ Production cost. $[EUR/MWh]$
- $Q \in \mathbb{N}$ Upper limit of production. $[MW]$
- $q(t))\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ Production strategy at time $t \in \{0,1,2,\dots,24\}$. $[MW]$
- $q_{0} \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ Amount bought at time $t=24 $ last day. $[MW]$

The optimization problem consists of finding the production strategy $q(t)$ at $t=1,2,...,24$. Which produces maximum profit.
Given $K, Q, q_{0}$ og $s(1), s(2),..., s(24)$

\begin{aligned}
\underset{q( \cdot )}{\max} \sum_{t=1}^{24} & q(t)[s(t)-K] \\
\text{ubb.} & \\
q(t) & \leq Q, \quad t=1,...,24 \ \text{og} \  q(t) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}\\
|q(t)-q(t-1)| & \leq 0,4 \cdot Q, \quad t=1,...,24 \\
q(0) & =q_0
\end{aligned}

With $Q=300$ we made a graph to describe the problem, containing $24 \cdot 300$ vertices, one for each MW in a given hour. And edges within the constraint $|q(t)-q(t-1)|  \leq 0,4 \cdot Q$.

To solve the problem we have implemented Dijkstra's algorithm, which works great.

What we noticed is that our solutions seems to choose the same values of $q(t)$. When productions needs to be decreased, because $(s(t)-K) < 0$ and when productions needs to be increased, because $(s(t)-K) > 0$. The values are {0,60,120,180,240,300}. Which sort of makes sense since when production needs to be decreased you would want to do it as fast as possible, in this case by decreasing production by 120 MW in each hour. The opposite being true when increasing production.

### Question

What we have been wondering is if there are any way of mathematically proving that the optimal solution only contains the vertices with value {0,60,120,180,240,300}?
Thereby being able to remove all the redundant vertices from the graph.

We know the problem can be seen as a linear programming problem and that if a feasible solution exists and if the (linear) objective function is bounded, then the optimum value is always attained on the boundary of the optimal level-set. But how do you go about proving which values are on the boundary?

Comment: Without the whole data set I can´t say anything about your question. But what I can say is that the constraint $|q(t)-q(t-1)|\leq 0.4Q$ is not linear. This constraint should be linearized if you want a linear model.